# A set has been encountered that cannot contain calculated members error in SSAS

Tags: ssas, mdx, cubes, kpi

I am using analysis service 2010. Within the cube that I am using, I have a hierarchy which contains customers details. I made a function to calculate members from all countries according to their contents i.e. Europe, South America and North America. I then made a KPI with the following goal expressions:

Value Expression:

```
  [Measures].[ Profit]
```

Goal Expression

```
Case  
  When [Customer].[Customers]
    Is [Customer].[Customers].[Country].&[Europe]
      Then .25 
  When [Customer].[Customers]
    Is [Customer].[Customers].[Country].&[NorthAmerica]
      Then .20  
  When [Customer].[Customers]
    Is [Customer].[Customers].[Country].&[SouthAmerica]
      Then .15  
  Else .10 
End
```

Status Expression:

```
Case  
  When KpiValue("MarginProfitCountries") / 
       KpiGoal("MarginProfitCountries") > .60
    Then 1  
  When KpiValue("MarginProfitCountries")  /
       KpiGoal("MarginProfitCountries")  <= .60
  And
       KpiValue("MarginProfitCountries")  /
       KpiGoal("MarginProfitCountries") > .40
    Then 0
Else -1
END
```

Trend Expression:

```
Case  
  When IsEmpty(ParallelPeriod([Time].[CalendarSales].[CalendarYear],  
      1, [Time].[CalendarSales]))  
    Then 0  
  When  [Measures].[ Profit] >  
    (ParallelPeriod([Time].[CalendarSales].[CalendarYear],  
      1,[Time].[CalendarSales]), [Measures].[ Profit])  
    Then 1  
  When [Measures].[ Profit] =  
    (ParallelPeriod([Time].[CalendarSales].[CalendarYear],  
      1,[Time].[CalendarSales]), [Measures].[ Profit])  
    Then 0  
  Else -1  
End
```

Trying to set the goals to match the specific criteria. However, Whenever I try to process the KPI I get the following error:

> A set has been encountered that cannot contain calculated members

Is there any way I can process the calculated members as a single member?

Edit:

Calculation script

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Customer].[Customers].[All Customers].[Europe]
 AS [Customer].[Customers].[Country].&[Austria] +  [Customer].[Customers].[Country].&[Denmark] + [Customer].[Customers].[Country].&[Finland] +  [Customer].[Customers].[Country].&[France] +  
[Customer].[Customers].[Country].&[Germany] + [Customer].[Customers].[Country].&[Ireland] + [Customer].[Customers].[Country].&[Italy] + [Customer].[Customers].[Country].&[Norway] +
[Customer].[Customers].[Country].&[Poland] + [Customer].[Customers].[Country].&[Portugal] + [Customer].[Customers].[Country].&[Spain] + [Customer].[Customers].[Country].&[Sweden] +
[Customer].[Customers].[Country].&[Switzerland] + [Customer].[Customers].[Country].&[UK], 
VISIBLE = 1;   
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Customer].[Customers].[All Customers].[NorthAmerica]
 AS [Customer].[Customers].[Country].&[Canada] + [Customer].[Customers].[Country].&[USA] + [Customer].[Customers].[Country].&[Mexico], 
VISIBLE = 1;   
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Customer].[Customers].[All Customers].[SouthAmerica]
 AS [Customer].[Customers].[Country].&[Argentina] + [Customer].[Customers].[Country].&[Brazil] + [Customer].[Customers].[Country].&[Venezuela], 
VISIBLE = 1;
```

Comment: Are you sure that KPI is the culprit? If you change the goal to 1 does the cube process? That error usually means you have SCOPE([Measures].[Some Calculated Measure])

Comment: Thank you for your answer Greg. If I change the goal to 1 I still get the error. Doing the same process for goal 2 and 3 gives also the same error. I have summed the countries into three territories i.e. Europe, South and north Americas. Then I used the three territories as attributes that I wanted to compare with in the goal

Comment: so you are saying the kpi isn't the culprit? Do you have any scope statements in your Calculations tab?

Comment: The calculation is already made for the measure and used as an expression i.e [Measures].Margin.  I summed the countries from the Customers hierarchy and then used the calculated members (Europe, South, North Americas) in the goal expression

Comment: can you please comment out any scope statement containing a calculated measure?

Comment: I have add all codes in each expression in my KPI. I hope this will make it clear

Comment: do you have anything on the Calculations tab? I recommend you stop focusing on the KPIs tab.

Comment: This is how I made the calculated member for each location

Comment: can you go to the Calculations tab and click the Script View button in the toolbar and copy and paste it into your question please. I am looking for the word SCOPE

Comment: Just edited my question. Apologies if I misunderstood your previous comments